# How do you use CIN when working with CMake projects in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I'm trying to work with basic CIN / COUT on a C++ project using Visual Studio Code (on Windows). The project is setup with CMake. Everything builds correctly and when debugging in VSC using COUT I can display text. But when I try a CIN the program hangs and input isn't getting passed to the program.

Running the program from the Developer Command Prompt For VS2019 CIN works properly.

c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.22.27905/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "vector-of-bool.cmake-tools",
            "compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/build/compile_commands.json"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

settings.json

```
{
    "C_Cpp.configurationWarnings": "Disabled",
    "files.associations": {
        "algorithm": "cpp",
        "atomic": "cpp",
        "cctype": "cpp",
        "chrono": "cpp",
        "cmath": "cpp",
        "condition_variable": "cpp",
        "cstddef": "cpp",
        "cstdint": "cpp",
        "cstdio": "cpp",
        "cstdlib": "cpp",
        "cstring": "cpp",
        < ... omitted to make the question readable ... >
        "xstddef": "cpp",
        "xstring": "cpp",
        "xtr1common": "cpp",
        "xtree": "cpp",
        "xutility": "cpp"
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Don't you need the option `"cppStandard": "c++11",`? I think you use `cStandard` if you are looking to code in C, but for C++, you would use `cppStandard`...

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome! When I setup the project with VSC's templates, it didn't add the field. I added it ("cppStandard": "c++11",) and got the same results.